# Binding a TreeView to a graph of EF Entities

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, treeview

I am working on a small project to learn learning WPF MVVM. Everything was ok until I hit this hurdle: I tried to bind a tree view to an observable collection to show Departments and their Teachers. the data is loaded eagerly so no lazy loading.

here is my view model:

```
public class NavigationTreeViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private CV.Model.Context.CVContext _dbContext;

    public NavigationTreeViewModel()
    {
        _dbContext = new Model.Context.CVContext();
        LoadDepartments();
    }

    private void LoadDepartments()
    {
        var result = _dbContext.Departments.Include(a => a.Teachers);
        _departments = new ObservableCollection<Department>(result.ToList());
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Teacher> _teachers;
    public ObservableCollection<Teacher> Teachers
    {
        get { return _teachers; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _teachers, value); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Department> _departments;
    public ObservableCollection<Department> Departments
    {
        get { return _departments; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _departments, value); }
    }

}
```

I can setup my binding to show the name of the department and the teachers like so:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CV.Modules.Views.NavigationTreeView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CV.Modules.ViewModels"
         xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"             
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:NavigationTreeViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}" Margin="5">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Teachers}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>

</UserControl>
```

However this won't work if I want to show the name of the department in the parent entity and the Last Name of the Teachers in the children entities. so I changed the template of the tree view to the resources of the control based on this [article](http://www.codemag.com/article/1401031). Here is what I did:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TeacherLevel">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="DepartmentLevel"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TeacherLevel}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<TreeView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DepartmentLevel}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}"
          Margin="5"/>
```

This way Only the department's names would show but not the Last Name of the teachers. 
I noticed that no Intellisense is available when trying to access the properties of my entities, the only thing available for me is the properties in my viewModel. In my first binding attempt I can see all the department properties but not in my second binding attempt.

**My Question Is this, How do I bind a tree view to a multi-level entity graph showing different properties at each level?**

I am missing something very basic here but I can't put my finger on it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: google search for *mvvm wpf treeview* -> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode (first result)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Sir Rufo for the Links.

What was missing from my templates is the type of he data that I am binding to. DataType in the HierarchicalDataTemplate is required in order to know to which property I am binding to.

Both suggested solutions define the entities to be bound to the Tree View in the ViewModel.

My model is defined in a different assembly so I ended up referencing my model in my view. This way my view knows about my model, I am pretty sure that I am breaking the MVVM pattern doing this. I didn't like the idea of creating additional identical classes just to provide data-binding for my view.

Here how my code looks like now:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CV.Modules.Views.NavigationTreeView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CV.Modules.ViewModels"
         xmlns:data="clr-namespace:CV.Model;assembly=CV.Model"
         xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"             
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">

<UserControl.Resources>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Teachers}"
                              DataType="{x:Type data:Department}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:Teacher}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}" Margin="5"/>
</UserControl>
```

I am marking the link from SO as the answer because it pointed me to how to answer my question. 
I will edit this answer in the future when I find a solution that doesn't pollute the view with my model entities.
Cheers